# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "hincha" para referirse a un seguidor de un equipo deportivo?

Tags: historia, deportes, uruguay

El DLE recoge la palabra *hincha*, cuya acepción más común actualmente es la relacionada con el deporte:

> [**hincha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KPbh4YZ)
>   De *hinchar*.
>
> 1. f. coloq. Odio, encono o enemistad.
> 2. m. y f. Partidario entusiasta de alguien o algo, especialmente de un equipo deportivo.

Buscando un poco me encuentro en el foro del Centro Virtual Cervantes [esta posible explicación](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=16549#58667) al comentario de otro preguntando si realmente viene de Uruguay:

> Algo de eso debe de haber. En el [glosario de términos futbolísticos usados en América](http://www.elcastellano.org/glosafut.html) puede leerse:
>
> > Hincha. (1910) Uruguayismo. Forofo, seguidor. En los partidos que disputaba el Nacional de Montevideo, se hacía oír a lo largo del encuentro el grito «¡Arriba Nacional!». Se popularizó el grito y cuando se preguntaba que quién lo emitía, se respondía que Reyes, el que hincha los balones del club a pleno pulmón.

¿Hay referencias al respecto? ¿Es esta la explicación real?

Comment: La primera acepción, la de "odio, encono o enemistad" aparece así tal cual ya en el Diccionario de Autoridades (1734).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La palabra se recoge por primera vez en el DLE con la acepción de "partidario fanático de un equipo de fútbol" en su edición de 1970. Es pues algo aparentemente reciente. Sin embargo, se encuentran casos anteriores a esa fecha en el CORDE, curiosamente entrecomillados dando a entender que la palabra se usaba como si fuera una jerga reciente:

> *—¡Vamos por la séptima Copa! —dijo aquel "hincha" del Madrid.*
>
> Meigallo, "Puyazos" [El Pito. Revista deportiva de humor para adultos, 2 de mayo de 1967].

Antes de 1950, todos los casos que encuentro son conjugaciones del verbo *hinchar* o de la acepción de "odio". Así que nos pasamos a la Hemeroteca y encontramos que el entrecomillado debía ser por no estar la palabra aún registrada oficialmente, porque hay casos de varias décadas antes:

> *Yo no sé si la prometida de «Handicap» es hincha del Celta.*
>
> El Heraldo de Madrid. 12/11/1930, página 10.

No encuentro casos anteriores a 1930 pero a partir de ahí se encuentran bastantes casos, por lo que la palabra debió de llegar a España sobre esa época. La hemeroteca del diario ABC confirma este dato ya que el primer caso así es también de noviembre de 1930:

> *Y así presenciamos el encuentro unas docenas de personas entre* hinchas, *incondicionales y críticos.*
>
> ABC. Domingo 2 de noviembre de 1930. Edición de Andalucía, pág. 39.

El problema es que estas hemerotecas solo tienen documentos de España. Si el origen está en Uruguay habrá que consultar otras fuentes. En la hemeroteca de la BIBNA podemos leer:

> *[...] la discusión, entablada entre sus partidarios [del peludo Maeso] por un lado y los* hinchas *del poeta Basso Maglio, por otro, acerca de [...].*
>
> La Pluma, Año 3, v. 10 (feb. 1929).

El primer caso que encuentro no es muy anterior pero tiene la particularidad de que no habla de los *hinchas* de ningún equipo de fútbol, sino de un poeta.

Buscando en el Fichero General de la RAE (más que nada porque el buscador de la hemeroteca de la Biblioteca Nacional de Argentina no me quiere hacer caso) veo que hay algunas fichas que sitúan su origen en Argentina además de en Uruguay, y que la definen como "fervientes defensores de una causa", dándole un sentido más general. Precisamente habla de Argentina una ficha que dice:

> En el habla porteña se aplica al 'Fanático de un equipo deportivo' porque fastidia y molesta.

**Este origen es el que llevo elucubrando desde que empecé a redactar: que las dos acepciones deben de estar relacionadas. Si viendo un partido se te pone a tu lado un *hincha* del equipo contrario, cuanto más grite y pasión le ponga más *hincha* le tomarás.**

Otras fichas aclaran que la palabra se popularizó España por la llegada de futbolistas profesionales argentinos y uruguayos. De ahí que la palabra aparezca en España más tarde, y a partir de una fecha concreta. Sería interesante ver qué jugador o jugarores de fútbol profesionales llegaron a España a finales de 1930. Aunque también pudo importarla algún cronista deportivo que viajara a aquellos países por la época (en alguna ficha apuntan a Jacinto Miquelarena).

Answer (score 2):

En muchísimos sitios, algunos generalmente fiables (como [la web de Ricardo Soca](http://www.elcastellano.org/palabra/hincha), recogida también por [Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?hincha), o el de [Alfred López](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/por-que-al-seguidor-de-un-equipo-se-le-llama-hincha/)), además de algún diario deportivo como el [As](https://as.com/tikitakas/2016/10/25/portada/1477377329_210555.html) o incluso la página de la [Liga de Fútbol Profesional](https://www.laliga.es/noticias/origen-de-la-palabra-hincha) española se da el mismo origen: la historia de un uruguayo llamado Prudencio Miguel Reyes.

Según esta historia, Reyes trabajaba a principios del siglo pasado como utillero en el Nacional de Montevideo, uno de los principales clubes de fútbol de Uruguay. Su trabajo consistía, entre otras cosas, en hinchar los balones que usaba el equipo en partidos y entrenamientos; de ahí que lo llamaran *hinchabalones* y, de ahí, simplemente *hincha*, apodo con el que se hizo popular.

El caso es que el *hincha* se distinguía durante los partidos por su fervor animando al equipo; y, como era un individuo muy popular, su apelativo pasó a usarse también para describir a cualquier otro aficionado especialmente animoso. Y, finalmente, la palabra entró en uso general entre los aficionados al fútbol.

Lo único que no he encontrado es referencias más antiguas sobre esta historia. Así que no puedo asegurar que sea cierta; podría ser una historia que alguien se inventó y ha acabado circulando por ahí. Pero me parece bastante verosímil, teniendo en cuenta la afición al fútbol en el Cono Sur y cómo se vivían los partidos hace un siglo.

Answer (score 0):

Solo para complementar lo ya mencionado, en el cuento *[Teníamos un juguete](https://editorialorsai.com/teniamos_un_juguete/)* de Hernán Casciari dice

> (...)Nosotros nos involucrábamos, tirábamos kilos de papel picado para recibir a los nuestros y componíamos canciones de aliento (...) Nos divertíamos durante la semana inventando estrofas, y hasta empezamos a componer otras, más picarescas, para fastidiar al vecino (...) Empezamos a decirle «hinchar» a la acción de fastidiar al rival con canciones picarescas. Y nos bautizamos a nosotros mismos «hinchas», y al grupo enfervorizado de la tribuna le pusimos de nombre «hinchada»(...)

Aunque no vienen los años en los que se usa el término, pero se toma el origen desde la burla al rival, si bien es bastante reciente el cuento.